# zip two arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays in javascript:

```
var array1 = ["a","b","c"];
var array2 = ["e","f","g"];
```

And I want the resulting array to be like this:

```
array3 = ["a","e","b","f","c","g"];
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Would that be the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874818/problem-in-concatenation-of-objects-in-javascript ?

Comment: What you want is not concatenation. You have confused at least four people with that title (three answerers and me).

Comment: Sorry I thought it counted as a concatenation too... I don't know the right word for what I want

Comment: it is "zip" zipping 2 arrays

Comment: I think you should first work on the basics!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Will a straightforward loop do it?

```
array3 = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
{
    array3.push(array1[i]);
    array3.push(array2[i]);
}
```

Comment: Answer could be more robust, if you have different length arrays for instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `concat()` method:

```
var array1 = ["a","b","c"];
var array2 = ["e", "f","g"];

var array3 = array1.concat(array2); // Merges both arrays
```

For your specific requirement, you have to follow this:

```
function mergeArrays(a, b){
    var ret = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        ret.push(a[i]);
        ret.push(b[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This will result in the wrong order of elements!

Comment: This is not what I need, please see the example in my question

Comment: I have updated my answer as per your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
function zip(source1, source2){
    var result=[];
    source1.forEach(function(o,i){
       result.push(o);
       result.push(source2[i]);
    });
    return result
}
```

Look http://jsfiddle.net/FGeXk/

It was not concatenation, so the answer changed.

Perhaps you would like to use: http://underscorejs.org/#zip